# What is the purpose of an empty struct with template arguments?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I'm reading some C++ CUDA code, which goes as follows:

```cpp
  using Q_vec = typename Vec<scalar_t, VEC_SIZE>::Type;
  const scalar_t* q_ptr = q + seq_idx * q_stride + head_idx * HEAD_SIZE;
  __shared__ Q_vec q_vecs[THREAD_GROUP_SIZE][NUM_VECS_PER_THREAD];
#pragma unroll
  for (int i = thread_group_idx; i < NUM_VECS_PER_THREAD; i += NUM_THREAD_GROUPS) {
    const int vec_idx = thread_group_offset + i * THREAD_GROUP_SIZE;
    q_vecs[thread_group_offset][i] = *reinterpret_cast<const Q_vec*>(q_ptr + vec_idx * VEC_SIZE);
  }
```

The definition of `Vec` is:

```cpp
// A vector type to store Q, K, V elements.
template<typename T, int VEC_SIZE>
struct Vec {};
```

I'm trying to understand what `q_vecs` is actually storing. `Vec` is an empty struct, so I don't think it's actually storing `VEC_SIZE` pieces of data. So, is it storing a pointer to `VEC_SIZE` pieces of data?

There are specializations defined, but they don't seem to do much:

```
// FP16 vector types for Q, K, V.
template<>
struct Vec<uint16_t, 1> {
  using Type = uint16_t;
};
```

Comment: It is a near certainty that this template has a bunch of specializations defined. The purpose of an empty struct with template arguments is to declare a template that instantiates to an empty struct no matter what the template arguments are.

Comment: It could also be that it just acts as type-carrier.

Comment: If `Vec` had no specializations, `typename Vec<scalar_t, VEC_SIZE>::Type` would fail to compile.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik there are specializations defined -- they just don't seem to do much.

Comment: Well, whatever they do, that must be their purpose.